# Remove GRUB and keep Windows Boot Loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows

There are similar questions to this but I'd like to ask specifically in the context of my issue. I have on two different partitions of the same SSD an installation of Windows 10, and an installation of Ubuntu 16.04. By default when I turn on my computer it goes to the nice blue windows boot screen that gives me the option to boot in Windows 10 or Linux. I created this using EasyBCD, and this is what I want. However, if I select Linux there is a small annoyance where it goes to GRUB and asks me again if I want to boot to Ubuntu or Windows 10. I would like not to see this screen, and I know that to do this I can just hide GRUB. But is there a way to completely remove GRUB just for organization/space considerations and rely entirely on the windows booter to boot Linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You **can** remove grub, but it would be unwise to do that. GRUB boots Ubuntu because it knows how to start the Linux kernel, like the Windows boot loader knows how to start the Windows kernel.

You can't expect Windows to boot an alien system from its boot loader, just like GRUB doesn't actually boot the Windows kernel - it just switches to the Windows boot loader.

You mention space and organisation, but GRUB really doesn't use that much space. On a server I logged in to which uses GRUB to boot the operating system, I found it only used 98MB of space and typically is found hidden away in the /boot folder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't handle grub or the Linux (`ext4`) file-system.  Removing grub and you remove access to Ubuntu.  To regain access you would have to reinstall Grub.

There are other boot loaders that you can install to boot Ubuntu such as:

- LILO
- SYSLINUX
- FreeLoader

This list is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_boot_loaders which has a large list.  You can explore the various alternatives to find one that might meet your needs better.

Alternatively you could use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) to have a GUI interface for the look and options.  The options includes hiding which menuitems are showing.

Grub Customizer PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```